# Unable to Load Content from JS to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, tracker

I am trying to build a workout tracker. I am using two JS files. The main.js is supposed to load content from the second (workoutTracker.js) into to the index.html. However, for some reason the content in not being loaded onto the page. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Fitness Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script href="main.js" type="module"></script>
    <script href="workoutTracker.js" type="module"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <!--
          <table class="tracker">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Workout</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tracker__entries">
              <tr class="tracker__row">
                <td><input type="date" class="tracker__date" /></td>
                <td>
                  <select type="text" class="tracker__workout">
                    <option value="walking">Walking</option>
                    <option value="biking">Biking</option>
                    <option value="fitness">Fitness</option>
                    <option value="running">Running</option>
                    <option value="meditation">Meditation</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="number" class="tracker__duration" />
                  <span class="tracker__text">minutes</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" class="tracker__button">&times;</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="tracker__row tracker__row--add">
                <td colspan="4">
                  <button class="tracker__add">Add Entry &plus;</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS (main.js):

```
import workoutTracker from "./workoutTracker.js";

const app = document.getElementById("app");

new workoutTracker(app);
```

JS (workoutTracker.js):

```
export default class workoutTracker {
  constructor(root) {
    this.root = root;
    this.root.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", workoutTracker.html());
    this.loadEntries();
    this.updateView();
  }
  static html() {
    return `
    <table class="tracker">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Workout</th>
          <th>Duration</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="tracker__entries">
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="tracker__row tracker__row--add">
          <td colspan="4">
            <button class="tracker__add">Add Entry &plus;</button>
            <!--<span class="tracker__add">Add Entry &plus;</span>-->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    `;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a CSS problem? How is this related to [tag:performance] or [tag:tracker]?

Comment: I have corrected my typo (from href to src) and have also positioned the script tag above the </body> tag. The page is still blank and the content is not being loaded.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: The issue was that I was receiving the files from my hard drive instead of using a live server. Once I installed the extension "Live Server", I was able to load the content on the page. Thank you guys for your contributions. The issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It's because script tag has src="" not href=""
just replace href with src

```html
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="workoutTracker.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, the code still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Only include the main script where you will be loading your modules with a `defer` attribute by default which tells
the browser to defer the execution of the script until all HTML is done parsing or the alternative is to place the script at the bottom before the end of the body tag which ensures that the script will only be loaded if all the HTML is done parsing(in this case the defer attribute will not be needed).
There is no need of including the `workoutTracker.js`  module as it will be loaded once the main module is parsed and executed.

```
     <script  src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <title>Fitness Tracker</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
            <!-- modules by default use the defer attribute which waits for the HTML to be parsed and before executing the JS or placed inside the body at the end -->
            <script  src="./main.js" type="module"></script> 
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Use the above snippet and make sure you are loading the workoutTracker.js module correctly

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, the code still does not load.

Comment: What is not working, and what do you expect to see on the scree once it is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Replace "Script href"'s with "Script src"'s. Also move those script elements above closing "body" element. (just like at following)

```
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="workoutTracker.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it, especially as the code snippet given looks like one from another answer that is four hours older

Comment: that doesn't matters where you put your script tag, inside body or outside of the body tag. but you should always put your script tag below your body tag.